# How to fix PHP nested loop I am getting some problem when I am trying to make a nested loop?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop, nested

I am expecting:

```
*usa
    london
    california
    sanfransisco
    
*saudiarabia
    makkah
    madina
    jeddah
```

but I am getting only 1st country like:

```
*usa
    london
    california
    sanfransisco
```

my database looks like this:

```
country         city
---------   ------------
usa             london

usa             california

usa             sanfransisco

saudiarabia     makkah

saudiarabia     madina

saudiarabia     jeddah
```

Codes I used:

```
   require('db_conn_setup.php');
$sql= "SELECT * FROM places";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0){
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      
echo '<ul>
        <li>'.$row["country"].
            '<ul>';
            if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {  
                echo '<li>'.$row["city"].'</li>';}
            '</ul>
        </li>
</ul>';
  } else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: I'd expect usa followed by all the cities, skipping the first:  London.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem is to stop using mysqli and start using PDO.

However, if you want to do the same using mysqli (which is more difficult) you need to first prepare your data and then loop accordingly on the multidimensional array.

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM places";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$data = [];
foreach($result as $row) {
    $data[$row['country']][] = $row['city'];
}
```

Then in your presentation logic you can loop on this array like so:

```
if($data) {
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($data as $country => $cities) {
        echo '<li>'.$country;
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach($cities as $city) {
            echo '<li>'.$city;
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

In PDO you could replace the first part just with this:

```
$data = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM places")
            ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```